# Would event.timeStamp and Date.getTime have the same reference?

Tags: javascript

Would [`event.timeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.timeStamp) and [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) return same values if taken at the exact same time?

For instance, could I use `getTime()` in order to calculate how much time passed since an event occurred, or might it happen that the 2 use different epoch / references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're always on the same reference, that is UTC, which is the time zone of all date internal storages.

You can also use `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser.

Using the following HTML document I got different results using different browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="foo">onclick delay:</div>
<button onclick='var n=document.getElementById("foo"); n.innerHTML="onclick delay: "+((new Date).getTime()-event.timeStamp)+"ms"'>Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The delay printed on screen is:

Firefox: large number

IE:  -4ms .. 0ms

Chrome: 0ms .. 2ms

Opera:  0ms .. 2ms

=> You cannot really use it if your code should work in different browsers.